# When I redeploy my google project ID, I see an error in gcloud.app.deploy saying Insufficient permissions to create Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My google project ID is "ulapph-public-1" and its been working fine since 2015. But yesterday when I redeployed the project, it says:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Insufficient permissions to create Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The link to the Google Cloud Storage is no longer accessible as well:
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ulapph-public-1.appspot.com?project=ulapph-public-1

Then the Google Cloud Storage browser says this error:
A required resource is not available.
Tracking Number: c4898802499062169

I tried checking the IAM but no luck, the deploy won't proceed. I even tried going to Appengine->Settings->Default Cloud Storage Bucket then the button I see there is "Create" but when I click it the error says "Default Cloud Storage Bucket creation failed".

I also checked the cloud storage browser settings and I noticed that there is no associated service account for the cloud storage. Compared to my other project IDs, I usually see here the service account like:

```
service-123456789012@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

```
Cloud Storage Service Account
Each project has an associated Cloud Storage service account. This is used to perform certain background actions: receiving PubSub notifications and encrypting/decrypting KMS encrypted objects.
```

Is there anyone who is familiar with this issue? 
- How do I manually add the missing service account service-123456789012@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com?
- What could have triggered the removal of the service account?

```
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [7] Insufficient permissions to create Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "resourceName": "staging.ulapph-public-1.appspot.com",
      "resourceType": "cloud storage bucket"
    }
  ]
]

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Insufficient permissions to create Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "resourceName": "staging.ulapph-public-1.appspot.com",
      "resourceType": "cloud storage bucket"
    }
  ]
]
```

Note that all my other google projects are working fine and the billing is fine but I only have Bronze support package so I can't connect to a technical support.